# Installing/Upgrading MikTeX without TeXworks

Tags: miktex, installing, texworks

Is it possible to install/upgrade MikTeX without TeXworks?

I'm using other tex editor for LaTeX and I think that I don't need the TeXworks.
I have uninstalled TeXworks using the MikTeX console, but when upgrading the package *miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9* (version 0.6.5) is selected to be installed and with *required* state without possibility to unselect the package.

Second question: why the TeXworks package is required?

Comment: This the wrong place to ask this. Go to the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: @faramir TeXworks binaries belong to MiKTeX's `S` (essential) set of packages/bundles. Therefore, upon every update, MiKTeX will check whether it is installed or not. I would say it is not required but "wanted to be present on purpose by MiKTeX's admins" (probably as every other binary). But what Ulrike suggested - there is an official communication channel for MiKTeX, you should ask there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. For interested people, the issue page is here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/582